# Flutter 'WebView' isn't defined and 'initialURL' not working. though dependency has been set

Tags: android, flutter, webview

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';


class SafeWebView extends StatelessWidget {
  final String? url;
  SafeWebView({this.url});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: WebView(
        initialUrl: url,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

WebView is not defined when  i already set the dependencies.
initalURL not showing

Comment: what version do you use? in the documentation , they provide to use  `WebViewWidget(controller: controller)` https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter